# How to pass a variable value from jquery to java class?

Tags: jquery

Please tell me how to pass a variable value from jquery to java class?

Comment: can you post some relevant code? and by java class you mean `method`?

Comment: Yes method in a java class I need to send a jquery varible to taht method

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery AJAX you could send data to any server side script: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/